# Bootstrap how to reduce the padding space between the columns without breaking the layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

We always get a default padding in bootstrap and I want to reduce it not totally remove it but without breaking the layout and responsiveness.
Here in this code I want to reduce the space between the two columns.

[image: I want to reduce the space here]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 image">
        <div>Some content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 content">
        <div>Some Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post a working example of your problem with your related HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 3):

Add a class to your div to set the padding to what ever percentage you want. Using percentages will keep it responsive.

CSS

```
.setpad {
  padding: the-percentage; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 image set setpad">
        <div>Some content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 content setpad">
        <div>Some Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct from Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

> - Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding.

```
.col-lg-1, ... {  
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

If you don't want to create a custom class that will reduce the padding, you can set the padding on your `.image` class. Here's a fiddle example for your review http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/m4favurs/

Comment: If we reduce padding in col-lg-* and col-md-* classes, why it is stretching out page little more at both sides. Can you please explain this...it will be helpful for me to know...